# How to create map in tableau

Tags: mapping, tableau-api

I'm trying to create an interactive map of Food Standards Agency data. I thought it would be a trivial part of creating a dashboard that I've created before.

However, what appears to look like this when I set the relevant measures:

[image]

Why does it become this when I click the button for mapping?

[image]

And why has the latitude moved to the rows row?

UPDATE: Thank you to Bernardo for his explanation.

What I want to recreate is a dashboard like the one I did in Python http://elksie5000.pythonanywhere.com/portfolio

Comment: The second setup you show will create a separate map for each combination of rating and business name. Try putting rating on colour and business name on detail or tooltip. Plus, you might need more robust data to link postcode to lat/lon as it looks like tableau isn't geocoding your postcodes correctly (full UK lookup files are available from ONS).

Answer (score 2):

There is a much simpler approach:

1. create a new sheet with no filters present.
2. double click longitude and latitude fields, one after the other
3. After the Map is **AUTO GENERATED**, use your Business name field as a second layer of the Map
4. you can find more info here : https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/maps_howto_simple.htm

Comment: If this helped you solve your issue, please mark as solved

Answer (score 1):

For maps, longitude goes on columns as the run vertically in a map. Likewise latitude goes on rows as those run horizontally. Then set the mark type to Map.

[image]

Now place your Business Name and Rating Value on the map layers.

Comment: How do I turn it into map rather than several? I can hardly put this on the web when it is a series of grey maps with no datapoints.

Comment: Only have the lat and lon on the rows / columns. place dimensions on the layers.